# How to replace custom words inside of DataTable word?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I use jquery DataTable framework such as this :

```
 $('.dataTable').dataTable({
                        "aaSorting": [[4, "asc"]]
  });
```

It worked currently but I need to use this datatable in another language .At the result I need to change words of datatable such as search,next,prev and ... to another words.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. **Datatables** give us the option to change the prefered language as a **plug-in**.

There are two methods by which you can include internationalisation options in DataTables - loading the language file through an Ajax request (`language.url: *prefered language*`), or at initialisation time using the (`language: *prefered language*`) property.

The following example shows how to include the German translation as an Ajax file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
        }
    } );
} );
```

To know more: 
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/

Hope this helps.